# How to insert a null value in Sequelize with omitNull flag?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an instance of Sequelize with the flag omitNull to insert de defaultValues defined in the DB if i do not define them in the create method of a model. Like this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pw', {
  omitNull: true
})
```

But I want to insert null values in other models if I define them as null. Like:

```
SomeModel.create({some_property: null});
```

Is there a way to define the omitNull property just for some properties of a model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `omitNull = true` option there is a way to force sequelize to set a property null.

Just do something like this:

```
SomeModel.some_property = null;
SomeModel.save(['some_property']);
```

This will force sequelize to create the update/insert SQL with NULL for `some_property`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I came across this issue today and your solution is working well for me.
@vistur: Please accept this answer

Comment: I could not believe that this is still the only way, but it is actually true...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using sequelize < v2.0, a hackier, alternative solution would be to

```
sequelize.options.omitNull = false;

SomeModel.some_property = null;
SomeModel.save();

sequelize.options.omitNull = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

although this question has been a long time, maybe someone needs this ..

```
  await User.update({
    someData: null
  },{
    omitNull: false,
    where: id,
  })
```

or

```
  await User.create({
    someData: null
  },{
    omitNull: false,
  })
```